# Difference between new Handler() and new Handler(Looper.myLooper())

Tags: android, android-handler

I went through the official docs, but i can't seem to find if there is any difference between `new Handler()` and `new Handler(Looper.myLooper())`

`new Handler()`

> Default constructor associates this handler with the Looper for the 
>   current thread.

`Looper myLooper ()`

> Return the Looper object associated with the current thread. Returns null 
>   if the calling thread is not associated with a Looper.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#myLooper()

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper()

Comment: I am not really sure why the -ve votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `Handler` [Source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Handler.java#202), if you don't provide the `looper`, it'll by default operate on the current looper from which the `Handler` is initialized, i.e `Looper.myLooper()`.

So

`new Handler()`

and

```
new Handler(Looper.myLooper())
```

are basically the same.

But the `Handler(Looper looper)` constructor can be used in situations where you want to change the thread other than the one from which the handle object is created.

For example, if you are in background thread and want to run something on main thread, you won't be simply able to do it with `new Handler()` as that handler will operate in the same thread.

Here you can use the constructor with Looper argument like:

`new Handler(context.getMainLooper())`

or

`Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) //if you don't have context`

Comment: I also am of the same view, that they are same.
Is there any situation where it could be different ?

Comment: Yes, for example, when you are running on background thread & want to run something on the main / ui thread, then you can pass `Looper.getMainLooper()` in `Handler` constructor to execute it on main thread.

Comment: @d3xter, I've edited my answer as well, hope it's clear now

Comment: The question is not at all about the `getMainLooper()` ; its about the default `new Handler()` and `new Handler(Looper.myLooper)`

Comment: What's unclear in that? The things you are saying, are both 100% equal. The `Handler(Looper looper)`  constructor is for the purpose when you want to operate the Handler in other thread instead of the thread returned by `Looper.myLooper()`

Answer (score 0):

**Handler()**
This constructor is deprecated now.

hence, we need to use  :

```
  Handler(Handler.Callback callback)   OR

  Handler(Looper looper)               OR

  Handler(Looper looper, Handler.Callback callback)
```

in order to create an instance of Handler in android.

for details you can check this link :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler